# Error 'An unknown error occurred when syncing from App Store Connect' is displayed when try to sync storeKit configuration from App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, storekit, storekittest

When attempting to sync storeKit configuration from App Store Connect, an error message stating '`An unknown error occurred when syncing from App Store Connect`' is displayed.

`Xcode: Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)`

BundleID is same with setting in App Store Connect.